# Plotting a 2D histogram using x, y and a cartesian product array. (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I have three arrays, the x and y arrays represent the locations of the bins while the z array is a 2d Cartesian product array of the probabilities associated with the location of each bin.

I have managed to plot this using contourf in mathplotlib such that:

```
plt.contourf(x, y, z, 25)
plt.show()
```

However as my x and y data is the location of bins rather than contours, the resultant graph isn't completely accurate.

I've also tried using histogram2d in mathplotlib, but I'm having trouble using the Cartesian product array as a z (colour) axis.

I should also note that the Cartesian product is not just a product, in my case I manipulated it further but its shape and relation to x and y remains as that of a Cartesian product.

Am I missing something obvious or is there no simple way to plot this as a histogram with the way my data is now? Thanks for your help!

My current plot using contourf looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyZR8.jpg

While i want to end up with a 2d histogram (ideally)

A sample of the relevant data is located here: http://pastebin.com/m54bfJ2A

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: Would you prefer raw data, or maybe one of the plots I got using contourf?

Comment: Both maybe? :P The example data is so that anyone who tries to answer has something to work with/test with. The example plot image would be good so people know what it should roughly look like. As you only have 1 rep you probably won't be able to add the image directly to your question. I'd suggest you upload it to imgur and add it. Also if you could add the data to pastebin.com rather than cluttering the question that would be best.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I could only post two links unfortunately, but my end result should look like a 2d histogram (http://imgur.com/fAZ5LgG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

Or [similar functions](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html). For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(8)
y = np.arange(6)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = xx + yy

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='Blues')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Note that `plt.hist2d` actually computes an histogram and then plot it, while, if I understood you correctly, you are only trying to plot a 2D array here. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I ended up using imshow which is quite similar. One thing to note though is that you have to use the "extent" parameter in imshow to get the x and y axis labelled correctly, such that:
fig = plt.imshow(z, origin = 'lower', vmin = 0, vmax = 1, extent = [x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()], interpolation='none', aspect = 'auto')